# Email not sending to email address with the same domain

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Our website is not sending contact form 7 email to address that have the same domain in the email address.

Comment: Sounds like a mail server problem.  But you should double check that the `from address` in Contact Form 7 has the same domain in it as the website domain.  The from address can be found when editing the form mail section.  I believe the from address also MUST exist as an actual mail address.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem couple of times in the past.

In my case all of the times it was the server not sending actual mail to email using the same domain. Though the emaill is hosted on someplace else.

Please contact host support to find out if your server is actually sending mails when the recipient is the same domain.

There is also an option in my WHM to stop sending mails on same domain, you might need to turn that off